# Processing API data (json) into a singular data frame (list of list of dictionaries)?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

So this is a somewhat of a continuation from a previous post of mine except now I have API data to work with. I am trying to get keys Type and Email as columns in a data frame to come up with a final number. My code:

```
jsp_full=[]
for p in payloads:
    payload = {"payload": {"segmentId":p}}
    r = requests.post(url,headers = header, json = payload)
    #print(r, r.reason)
    time.sleep(r.elapsed.total_seconds())

    json_data = r.json() if r and r.status_code == 200 else None

    json_keys = json_data['payload']['supporters']

    json_package = []
    jsp_full.append(json_package)
    for row in json_keys:
        SID = row['supporterId']
        Handle = row['contacts']
        a_key = 'value'
        list_values = [a_list[a_key] for a_list in Handle]
        string = str(list_values).split(",")
        data = {
            'SupporterID' : SID,
            'Email' : strip_characters(string[-1]),
            'Type' : labels(p)
        }
        json_package.append(data)



    t2 = round(time.perf_counter(),2)

    b_key = "Email"
    e = len([b_list[b_key] for b_list in json_package])
    t = str(labels(p))

    #print(json_package)
    print(f'There are {e} emails in the {t} segment')
    print(f'Finished in {t2 - t1} seconds')


    excel = pd.DataFrame(json_package)
    excel.to_excel(r'C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\{0} segment {1}.xlsx'.format(t, str(today)), sheet_name=t)
```

This part works all well and good. Each payload in the API represents a different segment of people so I split them out into different files. However, I am at a point where I need to combine all records into a single data frame hence why I append out to jsp_full. This is a list of a list of dictionaries.

Once I have that I would run the balance of my code which is like this:

```
S= pd.DataFrame(jsp_full[0], index = {0})
Advocacy_Supporters = S.sort_values("Type").groupby("Type", as_index=False)["Email"].first()
print(Advocacy_Supporters['Email'].count())

print("The number of Unique Advocacy Supporters is :")
Advocacy_Supporters_Group = Advocacy_Supporters.groupby("Type")["Email"].nunique()
print(Advocacy_Supporters_Group)
```

Some sample data:

```
[{'SupporterID': '565f6a2f-c7fd-4f1b-bac2-e33976ef4306', 'Email': 'somebody@somewhere.edu', 'Type': 'd_Student Ambassadors'}, {'SupporterID': '7508dc12-7647-4e95-a8b8-bcb067861faf', 'Email': 'someoneelse@email.somewhere.edu', 'Type': 'd_Student Ambassadors'},...`
```

My desired output is a dataframe that looks like so:

```
SupporterID                           Email                     Type
565f6a2f-c7fd-4f1b-bac2-e33976ef4306  somebody@somewhere.edu    d_Student Ambassadors
7508dc12-7647-4e95-a8b8-bcb067861faf  someoneelse@email.somewhere.edu d_Student Ambassadors
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I should note that when I try to translate into a Dataframe I get either errors like "Add index when passing scalar values" or I get too few records as with the code above. I have tried for nested for loops but can't seem to get the dictionary out of the nest (it returns empty). I have also attempted list comprehension as well but seems...difficult when crossing data structures.

Comment: Try `jsp_full.extend(json_package)`, then `S= pd.DataFrame(jsp_full)`.

Comment: That didn't work (too many columns) but I did figure out a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So because this code creates an excel file for each segment, all I did was read back in the excels via a for loop like so:

```
filesnames = ['e_S Donors', 'b_Contributors', 'c_Activists', 'd_Student Ambassadors', 'a_Volunteers', 'f_Offline Action Takers']

S= pd.DataFrame()
for i in filesnames:
    data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\am\Desktop\email parsing\{0} segment {1}.xlsx'.format(i, str(today)),sheet_name= i, engine = 'openpyxl')
    S= S.append(data)
```

This did the trick since it was in a format I already wanted.